# Make PC connect to local clients without router (via ethernet switch)

Tags: networking, routing, switch

I’ve been trying to make my Windows 10 PC route connections to local clients without a real router or LAN. I’ve been searching for router software, dhcp server software but without success. My problem isn’t complicated, maybe it works with netroute, but I don’t know how.

I only need to communicate with one client, my Philips Hue Bridge. I have access to WAN, local IP is given to me by my ISP and their gateway. My Hue Bridge is still stuck with 192.. address though. (I just gave my router up today)

I saw that HyperV switch can be beneficial. But how can I make it act like a gateway?

P.S the physical connection is allowed. My hue bridge tries to announce its IP and find a gateway, seen through Wireshark, can’t I translate its MAC address to some internal variable or IP?

Comment: If you can log in to each host, then configure/assign it to use a static IP address instead of a dynamic IP address from the DHCP server.

Comment: I don’t quite understand. Even if I forced the client to bind a specific IP, what IP would that be? I don’t have a local network, I don’t have a gateway, which is why I wanted my PC to fulfill those services virtually.

Comment: Can you use WiFi Direct? https://softwarekeep.com/help-center/what-is-wifi-direct-in-windows-10

Comment: No it’s too bad. Hue Bridge is wired only. I actually reset my bridge and it got a new IP from ISP gateway/dhcp. But the Philips software is so bad you can only enter IP addresses that start with 192... and besides, the ISP lease only lasts 1h